# Loop through videos and refresh after each

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops

I want to play multiple videos behind eachother. However, i want the page to refresh everytime a video is ended.

How do i do that?

Right now i have this:

```
<script>
    video_count =1;
    videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

    function run(){
            video_count++;
            if (video_count == 6) video_count = 1;
            var nextVideo = "Videos/demo/"+video_count+".mp4";
            videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
            videoPlayer.play();
       };
</script>
```

And

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source src="Videos/demo/1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Now this is working (The next video starts after the first finished.) 
However i don't know how to build in the auto refresh. without starting at the first video again.

**EDIT:**

Is it posible with php?

This is what i did right now:

```
<?php
$videos=array("Videos/treinen/1.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo/1.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo1/2.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo/2.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo1/3.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo/3.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo1/4.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo/4.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo1/5.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo/5.mp4",
    "Videos/Demo1/6.mp4"); 
echo $videos[0] . $videos[1] . $videos[2] . $videos[3] . $videos[4] . $videos[5] . $videos[6] . $videos[7] . $videos[8] . $videos[9];
?>
```

Is it posible

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $videos; ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is ofcourse not working yet, but i hope you guys get my idea.
(I wana store it via a session. and i'm using a iframe because of bootstrap).

Comment: Use cookies to store which video you're on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store somewhere `video_count`, because after refresh `video_count` will be refreshed too.

**You have few options:**

1. Store in session
2. Store in cookie
3. Store in database (work with Ajax)

**Session example:**

You can make it pretty fast with this plugin: https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Set session:

```
$.session.set("userName", $("#uname").val());
```

Get session:

```
$.session.get('userName');
```

Comment: Nah, mixing php and javascript variables isn't a good idea. Best thing is to go with cookies.

Comment: The problem with cookies is, that users can change them. That won't be the best idea if you want to display video ads etc.

Comment: Is it not posible with php? I just put all the path-directions in a array. Is it posible to store those in a session, en echo the array on the src location? I will edit it on main answer

Answer (score 0):

There are alot solutions to this problem. If you want to stick with your solution of redirecting you could use web storage or cookies.

```
function run(){
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        var video_count = localStorage.getItem("video_count");
        if (video_count === null) {
            video_count = 1;
        }
        //play video
        video_count++;
        //set new video count
        localStorage.setItem("video_count", video_count);
        //redirect
    }
};
```

A much better solution would be using ajax to return a new json with data to refresh content on your page and not use redirects at all.

```
function run(){
    //play next video without refreshing
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        success: function(response){
            //refresh data on page
            $('#content').html(response);
        }
    })
};
```